# What is Right way to get spark executing udf

Tags: pyspark, action, user-defined-functions

As fas as I know , the spark use lazy computation meaning if the `action` is not called, nothing would ever never happen .
And one way I know is using `collect` method get spark working , however when I read the [article](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-collect/) it says :

> Usually, collect() is used to retrieve the action output when you have
> very small result set and calling collect() on an RDD/DataFrame with a
> bigger result set causes out of memory as it returns the entire
> dataset (from all workers) to the driver hence we should avoid calling
> collect() on a larger dataset.

And I actually have `udf` that returns `NullType()`

```
@udf
def write_something():
    #write something to dir
```

so I do not want to use `collect()` ,cause it might cause `OOM` as mentioned above.

So in my case , what is the best way to do this in my case ? Thanks !

Comment: What are you trying to reach? Just log some data from workers during execution or write the data into a path?

Comment: @Kafels yes that's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @Kafels I am new to spark , not sure if this can really help me speed my file-writing process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dataframe.foreach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach.html):

```
df.foreach(lambda x: None)
```

The `foreach` action will trigger the excecution of the whole DAG of `df` while keeping all data on their respective executors.

The pattern `foreach(lambda x: None)` is mainly used for debugging purposes. An option might be to remove the udf and put its logic into the function that is called by `foreach`.